Issue with creating Apache Sedona context in 1.6.1
I'm using the Sedona docker image sedona:1.6.1 and trying to run one of the example notebooks but getting an error when running the Sedona Context step:
from sedona.spark import *
config = (
    SedonaContext.builder()
    .config(
        "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider",
        "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AnonymousAWSCredentialsProvider",
    )
    .config(
        "fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider",
        "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AnonymousAWSCredentialsProvider",
    )
    .config(
    )
    .getOrCreate()
)

sedona = SedonaContext.create(config)

Error:
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o0.set.
: java.lang.NullPointerException: null key
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:83)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:76)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:52)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)

Everything comes from the example Jupyter notebook as is, so cant see how I'm doing anything wrong. Anyone else had this issue / know what needs changing in the config?

The error says your config has extra empty configs. Please remove them from your code.
    .config(
    )

